# Using AudioContext stops the audio from playing in the background

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I've been playing around with the Web Audio API and ran into a weird problem.

At the moment, if you open a web page on your phone and click the play button on an HTML5 audio element, the audio will keep playing in the background even after switching apps.

However, when you attach the element to an AudioContext, the audio will **stop** playing in the background after switching apps.

To attach the element, I'm using the following:

```js
const context = new AudioContext()
const source = context.createMediaElementSource(document.querySelector("audio"))

source.connect(context.destination)
```

So even though I'm simply connecting the HTML5 audio element to the context's destination WITHOUT controlling it, the audio stops playing as soon as I switch apps.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get the audio to keep playing in the background even after switching apps? It's odd that we can use the Web Audio API to control audio on the web, but we have to keep our browsers open and our phones unlocked to listen to that audio.

Comment: I think browsers do this on purpose. The same way they will throttle and stop animations.

Comment: @TheFool, but HTML5 audio works fine in the background unless you attach an AudioContext, then it no longer works.

Comment: @HawaiianPizza previous commenter is correct, this is a desired behaviour, while your case with HTML5 audio seems like a bug on your particular device.

Comment: @YuriyKravets It works on every device, though, not just mine,

Comment: @HawaiianPizza did you find anything new to this topic?

Answer (score -2):

The intended behavior is for audio to stop on browser exit on phones, because it saves on background processing and from a user standpoint, I think the expected behavior would be that audio stops when you close out.

I think you just have audio working **incorrectly** on the specific device.

Comment: But Audio works as described on Android and iOS 12, 13, 14 and 15.